# Combining three tables to only deal with one

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these three tables in SQL for a game:

**user_stats** with primary key id

```
| userid | kills | deaths |
|--------|-------|--------|
|   10   |   5   |   4    |
```

**user_items** (the items the user has bought) with regular integer primary key id - when the user buys a new item, a row is added

```
| id | userid | itemid |
|----|--------|--------|
|  1 |   10   |   1    | 
|  2 |   10   |   2    | 
|  3 |   10   |   3    |
```

**user_details** (the items the user has equipped) with primary key userid

```
| userid | item1 | item2 |
|--------|-------|-------|
|   10   |   1   |   3   |
```

I only want to deal with one table, but I need all information when the user starts. I'd like to combine the three tables into one, but user_items has multiple rows for 1 user, because you can buy multiple items. Being a total stranger to SQL, how do I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a `join` on all three tables and get the specific data you want like below

```
select us.*
from user_stats us
inner join user_item ui on us.userid = ui.userid
inner join user_details ud on us.userid = ud.userid
```

Since all the tables have a common column `userid` you can as well use `NATURAL JOIN`

```
select *
from user_stats
natural join user_item
natural join user_details
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, guess I just overlooked this option :)

Comment: If I were to join the tables in this case, it would return 3 rows with all info in each row - because of the 3 rows in user_items, correct? If one user has a lot of items, say 50, would the join affect performance? What is a better approach?

Comment: @user1930226, that's correct. It may or may not. In your case, if you see all the 3 rows would be same (duplicate rows). So to avoid that just use  `distinct` keyword; which will end giving you only 1 unique row. See this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5a6d1/5